# Leader keys that don't take away functionality

Tags: vim

I've been thinking about remapping my leader key and I've been trying to think of all the options I have.

In particular, I'm looking for a list of symbols that, when pressed in normal mode without custom bindings, don't serve any useful purpose.
For sanity's sake, only symbols found on a US keyboard are considered, but to make the list somewhat layout-agnostic, we should not consider whether a modifier key is required to type it.

Finally, incredibly common commands will not be considered good leader options, even if they can be easily replaced. This is slightly subjective, but I'm talking about really basic commands here, like `h`, `j`, `k`, `l`, `w`, `d`, etc.

A commonly suggested leader key is `,`. I consider this a bad option, since it serves a useful purpose. When you press `;` too many times, going back with `,` is useful and there is no other easy way of replicating this action.

On the other hand, both `+` and `-` are good leader keys. While they aren't exactly the same as `j` and `k`, they are close enough that their absence won't be missed. (And I suspect most people will use something like `jw` over `+` if necessary)

So here is an incomplete list of symbols that I think fit this description:

- `+`  (can use `j`)
- `-` (can use `k`)
- `<space>` (can use `l`)
- `<CR>` (can use `j`)
- `<BS>` (can use `h`)
- `\`
- `<Del>` (can use `x`)
- `x` (can use `<Del>`)

What is the full list of such symbols and did I miss something in my current list that would disqualify a listed symbol?

PS: The reason I am asking this is not exactly because I am looking for a new leader key myself. (Although I am. It will probably be space) It just seems like such a list should exist and I haven't been able to find one. This might help others choose a sensible leader, as well and steer people clear of options like `,` that would deprive them of useful functionality they might not even realise exists at the time they choose their leader key.

Comment: Leader should be mapped to space, the biggest key on the keyboard, and like most vim defaults, space is useless out of the box

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22129/which-keys-are-free-unmapped-by-default

Comment: @AndyRay Nice! Not quite what I'm looking for, but a good start. While I do agree that space is a very good option, and probably the one I will adopt, it is not the definitive option. Other people might prefer a different key.

Comment: Every key you posted has functionality. Asking which ones are useful is an opinion question which isn't right for stack overflow. I accidentally retracted my "close: opinion based" vote, and now I can't re-apply it

Comment: I can't say that it isn't at least somewhat subjective, but I'd argue it's not really opinion-based. I'm looking for keys that have no useful functionality. i.e. functionality, that can easily be replicated without that key. Like space, for which you can just use L. It's not that moving one character to the right is not useful, it's that the functionality is duplicated.

Comment: Mapping `<CR>` has some pitfalls. For instance, in the quickfix window (or location list), `<CR>` is used to open that location in a buffer. Mapping `<CR>` (or using it as a prefix for mappings) typically interferes with that.